# QRegExp not matching as expected

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

i would like to match all strings that contain none of these characters "<",">","=" with QRegExp (Qt). With the folloing regexp, this is not working:

```
 "^[^><=]+$"
```

why? to me it means: beginning of string, one or more characters that are not >,<,= and end of string

thanks

EDIT

i would like to match

```
BUILD
```

for instance, and i would like not to match

```
BU<ILD
```

Comment: It often makes sense to provide an example of input that is being matched where you don't expect it. It provides a test-case for people answering your question and reduces the amount of guesswork.

Comment: The regexp and the samples you posted look fine. The problem could be with the way you do the matching in code. Please show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the other way to do it. Use:

`^(?!.*[<>=]).*$`